# How can I go to the next screen after taking a picture? SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, applescript

I have a problem with the navigation.
I need to take a photo and after that open a new screen with the button and the taken image. Now it opens the same screen but with the taken image.

Here is the first screen

[image: white screen with button in middle]

Here is the same screen, but I need another view here with another button

[image: photo with button underneath]

**ImagePicker**

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

class ImagePickerCoordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

    @Binding var isShown: Bool
    @Binding var image: Image?

    init(isShown: Binding<Bool>, image: Binding<Image?>) {
        _isShown = isShown
        _image = image
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        let uiImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as! UIImage
        image = Image(uiImage: uiImage)
        isShown = false
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        isShown = false
    }
}

struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    @Binding var isShown: Bool
    @Binding var image: Image?

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) {

    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> ImagePickerCoordinator {
        return ImagePickerCoordinator(isShown: $isShown, image: $image)
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) -> UIImagePickerController {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        if !UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera){
            picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        } else {
            picker.sourceType = .camera
        }
        return picker
    }
}
```

**ContentView**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var showImagePicker: Bool = false
    @State private var image: Image? = nil

    var body: some View {
        VStack {

            image?.resizable()
                .scaledToFit()

            Button("Attach the image") {
                self.showImagePicker = true
            }.padding()
                .background(Color.blue)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .cornerRadius(10)
        }.sheet(isPresented: self.$showImagePicker) {
            PhotoCaptureView(showImagePicker: self.$showImagePicker, image: self.$image)
        }
    }
}
```

**PhotoCaptureView**

```
import SwiftUI

struct PhotoCaptureView: View {

    @Binding var showImagePicker: Bool
    @Binding var image: Image?


    var body: some View {
        ImagePicker(isShown: $showImagePicker, image: $image)
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct PhotoCaptureView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PhotoCaptureView(showImagePicker: .constant(false), image: .constant(Image("")))
    }
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple, you can use NotificationCenter.
In didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo function, you can post a notification, and in ContentView use the publisher of notification to change a State value.
so in ContentView:

```
.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: Notification.Name("NotificationName"))) { _ in
  move.toggle()
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $move) {
        AnotherContentView()
        
    }
```

And in didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo function:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("NotificationName"), object: nil, userInfo: nil)
```